# Extremely slow Perforce transfer rates

Tags: networking, perforce, perforce-client-spec

Apologies if this is the wrong place to post, but you guys seem to be a wealth of information. I'm trying to sync a perforce project with a team in NZ and I'm based in the UK and no matter what connection I try I'm getting a hard sync limit of 2mbps up and down. I've tried two different PC's and two completely seperate internet connections with different providers.
The port 1666 is forwarded. All firewall rules are set to allow P4V to access. I'm not recieving any network or connection errors, it's just insanely slow. Our sys admin gave me an IP for the US server and this has the same issue, hard limit of 2mbps. I've tried VPNs.
My p4 info readout is instantaneous implying theres no issue with connecting to the server. Someone has tried using my account in NZ and it was fine so not an account issue.
Unfortunately Perforce support still haven't replied after a week and our network admin based in NZ isn't too familiar with it but can't see what the issue could be on his side of things. So reaching out to alternative means.

Running Windows 11. Workplace Ethernet connection and two different mobile hotspots have been tried. All yeild a hard sync cap of 2mbps. Zero issues with pulling file lists or connecting to the project in perforce. It's purely file transfer that is experiencing the latency. No Kaspersky

Comment: Very disturbing that Perforce Support hasn't responded. Call them?

Comment: Since you synced in NZ, can you run a test to transfer those NZ synced files to your UK site - this is to remove p4 from the mix.  Have you run your slow sync with "p4 -Ztrack sync <path>" and sent the output to support?